# Excel sumif in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

```
A   B      C
1  John
2  Mike
3  David
```

```
X    Y       z
1   Mike    100
2   Mike    200
3   John    300
4   David   400
5   David   500
```

I want to fill C column with the sum of Z corresponding to each name in Y.

The result should look like below:

```
A   B      C
1  John   300
2  Mike   300
3  David  900
```

I did it by creating a pivot using groupby, then merging it, however I would like to know if there's an elegant and faster method of doing it.

Comment: df1['C'] = df1['B'].map(df2.groupby('B')['C'].sum())

Comment: For what it's worth, your solution sounds quite reasonable.